# Trying to populate a nested array in mongoose a seemingly unrelated CastError is thrown and I can't understand why

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm new to mongoose and I'm trying some very basic experiments with references and schemas.

What I'm trying to do is to have an "installation" entity which contains an array of devices grouped by type. Inside of this group there is an array of ids of the single devices referenced.

My schemas are like these:

```
///INSTALLATIONS.js
var installationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    devices: [deviceType:String,
             ids: {type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'device'}}]
})

export const model = mongoose.model("installation", installationSchema);

///DEVICES
var deviceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    deviceType : String,
    code: String
})

export const model = mongoose.model("device", deviceSchema);
```

Populating the installation:

```
var installationsSchemaModel = require("INSTALLATIONS.js");
installationsSchemaModel.model.find().populate('devices.ids')
```

I get this error:

```
2016-06-23T15:40:26.328Z - error: installations  CastError: Cast to number failed for value "576ab1796c2672501fa69054" at path "_id"
```

Here is how my relevant data in mongo looks:

```
///INSTALLATION I'm trying to populate. The collection contains this single item
   {
    "_id" : 131,
    "devices" : [{
    "deviceType" : "TYPE1",
    "ids" : [ObjectId("576ab1796c2672501fa69054")]
   }]
   }

///DEVICE i'm trying to reference
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("576ab1796c2672501fa69054"),
    "deviceType" : "TYPE1"
   }
```

Why am I getting the cast error only trying to populate my collection?

I've tried changing the installation._id type to Number and the error whent away, but the population failed nonetheless: the obtained structure was with an empty devices array.

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: The `_id` property is MongoDB internal id you don't need (maybe even shouldn't) define it and definetely don't change its type! Don't do this `"_id" : 131,`. If you need custom id property in your schema just use something else maybe simply `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've resolved it.
I think Moida is wrong because the type change in _id field is covered also in the Mongoose official documentation.

The error was in the definition of the ids array. An array should be defined like this

```
ids: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "device"}]
```

The solution I've adopted in the question is not working despite the fact I've found it in different other posts on stackoverflow. I think it might be due to a previous version of Mongoose in which the definition of arrays could be done in both ways.